# SVG: reverse cubic and quadratic bezier curves

Tags: javascript, svg, cubic-bezier

I'm working on a script to [reverse the draw direction](https://github.com/thednp/svg-path-commander/blob/master/src/process/reversePath.js) of SVG path commands, everything is working smoothly so far but not with `S` path commands or `T`.

In one of [my implementations](https://github.com/thednp/svg-path-commander/blob/master/src/process/reverseCurve.js) for path reverse functionality based only on cubic bezier `C` curves, works flawlessly, however the output path string is considerably larger, sometimes double or triple the length.

Here's a simplified version of the `reversePath.js` which, so far, implements some basic handling for `S` and a test page:

```js
  // the script I'm working on works with these arrays
  var path = [['M',10,80],['C',40, 10, 65, 10, 95, 80],['S',150,150,180,80],['S',230,10,270,80]],
      target = document.getElementById('target');

// our focus is RIGHT HERE
function reversePath(pathInput){
  let isClosed = pathInput.slice(-1)[0][0] === 'Z',
      params = {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0, x: 0, y: 0, qx: null, qy: null},
      pathCommand = '', pLen = 0, 
      reversedPath = [];

  reversedPath = pathInput.map((seg,i,pathArray)=>{
    pLen = pathArray.length
    pathCommand = seg[0]

    switch(pathCommand){
      case 'M':
        x = seg[1]
        y = seg[2]
        break
      case 'Z':
        x = pathArray[0][1]
        y = pathArray[0][2]
        break
      default:
        x = seg[seg.length - 2]
        y = seg[seg.length - 1]
    }

    return {
      c: pathCommand, 
      x: x,
      y: y,
      seg: seg
    }
  }).map((seg,i,pathArray)=>{
    let segment = seg.seg,
        prevSeg = i && pathArray[i-1],
        nextSeg = pathArray[i+1] && pathArray[i+1],
        result = []

    pLen = pathArray.length
    pathCommand = seg.c
    
    params.x = i ? pathArray[i-1].x : pathArray[pLen-1].x
    params.y = i ? pathArray[i-1].y : pathArray[pLen-1].y

    switch(pathCommand){
      case 'M':
        result = isClosed ? ['Z'] : [pathCommand, params.x,params.y]
        break
      case 'C':
        if ('S' === nextSeg.c) {
          params.x2 = params.x1 + params.x2 / 2
          params.y2 = params.y1 + params.y2 / 2
          result = ['S', params.x2,params.y2, params.x,params.y]
        } else {
          params.x1 = segment[3]
          params.y1 = segment[4]
          params.x2 = segment[1]
          params.y2 = segment[2]
          result = [pathCommand, params.x1,params.y1, params.x2,params.y2, params.x,params.y];
        }
        break
      case 'S':
        params.x2 = params.x1 + params.x2 / 2
        params.y2 = params.y1 + params.y2 / 2

        if (nextSeg && 'S' === nextSeg.c) {
          result = [pathCommand, params.x2,params.y2, params.x,params.y]
        } else {
          params.x1 = params.x1 + params.x2 / 2
          params.y1 = params.y1 + params.y2 / 2
          params.x2 = segment[1];
          params.y2 = segment[2];
          result = ['C', params.x1,params.y1, params.x2,params.y2, params.x,params.y];
        }
        break
      case 'Z':
        result = ['M',params.x,params.y]
        break
      default:
        result = segment.slice(0,-2).concat([params.x,params.y])
    }    
    return result
  })
  return isClosed ? reversedPath.reverse() : [reversedPath[0]].concat(reversedPath.slice(1).reverse())
}

function pathToString(pathArray) {
  return pathArray.map(x=>x[0].concat(x.slice(1).join(' '))).join(' ')
}

function reverse(){
  var reversed = pathToString(reversePath(path));
  target.setAttribute('d',reversed)
  target.closest('.col').innerHTML += '<br><p class="text-left">'+reversed+'</p>'
}
```

```css
.row {width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row}
.col {width: 50%; text-align: center}
.text-left {text-align: left}
```

```html
<button onclick="reverse()">REVERSE</button>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 270 160">
      <path id="example" d="M10 80 C40 10, 65 10, 95 80S 150 150, 180 80S 230 10 270 80" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
    </svg>
    normal path
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 270 160">
      <path id="target" d="M0 0L0 0" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
    </svg>
    reversed path (click the button)
  </div>
</div>
```

I started here from the the [Raphael.js](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L2122-L2132) implementation on converting S and Q and T path commands to `C` (cubicBezier), thinking and reverse engineering perhaps I could find a way to make it work.

So I need a little help figuring out a correct formula for these `S` and `T` path commands when reversing the shape. If someone can help me with `S` I can figure out myself on `T`.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: What is the purpose of the reversing?

Comment: Some vector libraries use `fill-rule="evenodd"`, if you wanna do font-icons, you need to reverse subpaths. Also reversing paths is important for SVG Morphing.

Comment: does svg-path-commander provide something like "normalization", i.e. conversion (without any reversing yet) "H"->"L", "V"->"L", "T"->"Q", "S"->"C"? Then you could first "normalize" it and then reverse using existing approach. Or is the problem how to treat S and T in general? (I am a bit confused, sorry)

Comment: I concur with @JanStránský that the only sane way to solve this is to start out with a normalized sequence. In addition, I think you need to handle the coordinates and the segments that connect them separately: while the geometry (bezier, arc, line) of a segment is a property of that segment, the symmetry associated with the `S` and `T` commands is a property of the coordinate _before_ that command. That means when reversing, the simplification Q->T is applied to the same coordinate, but to another segment (always the one _after_ the coordinate).

Comment: The paths are always normalized, absolute paths.

Comment: The initial problem I though it was the ArcTo path commands, but I figured those out. The H->L / H->L "normalization" is not needed, if you go to svg-path-commander demo, you will be able to test various shapes, it's working fine except shorthand S and T, but I think the key to solving this is to do what you guys suggest only for these cases. I will update this as soon as I implement it right.

Comment: You certainly got my juices flowing. I have written an implementation that sits atop my own path parser for the [pathfit module](https://github.com/ccprog/pathfit). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ccprog/4692b04705f1d022077876b6aafe5922)

Comment: Thank you, very kind.

Comment: @ccprog I hope you like my solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the normalization did the trick. Also some new additions and more powerful value processing, but let's get to it, here's the updated function with new additions:

```js
// the script I'm working on works with these arrays
  var pathCubic = [['M',10,80],['C',40,10,65,10,95,80],['S',150,150,180,80],['S',230,10,270,80]],
      targetCubic = document.getElementById('target');

// the updated function
function reversePath(absolutePath){
  var isClosed = absolutePath.slice(-1)[0][0] === 'Z',
  reversedPath = normalizePath(absolutePath).map(function (segment,i){
    return {
      c: absolutePath[i][0],
      x: segment[segment.length - 2],
      y: segment[segment.length - 1],
      seg: absolutePath[i],
      normalized: segment
    }
  }).map(function (seg,i,pathArray){
    var segment = seg.seg,
        data = seg.normalized,
        prevSeg = i && pathArray[i-1],
        nextSeg = pathArray[i+1] && pathArray[i+1],
        pathCommand = seg.c,
        pLen = pathArray.length,
        x = i ? pathArray[i-1].x : pathArray[pLen-1].x,
        y = i ? pathArray[i-1].y : pathArray[pLen-1].y,
        result = [];
    switch(pathCommand){
      case 'M':
        result = isClosed ? ['Z'] : [pathCommand, x,y];
        break
      case 'C':
        if (nextSeg && nextSeg.c === 'S') {
          result = ['S', segment[1],segment[2], x,y];
        } else {
          result = [pathCommand, segment[3],segment[4], segment[1],segment[2], x,y];
        }
        break
      case 'S':
        if ( prevSeg && 'CS'.indexOf(prevSeg.c)>-1 && (!nextSeg || nextSeg && nextSeg.c !== 'S')) {
          result = ['C', data[3],data[4], data[1],data[2], x,y];
        } else {
          result = [pathCommand, data[1],data[2], x,y];
        }
        break
      case 'Z':
        result = ['M',x,y];
        break
    }
    return result
  });
  return isClosed ? reversedPath.reverse() : [reversedPath[0]].concat(reversedPath.slice(1).reverse())
}

// new additions
function shorthandToCubic(x1,y1,x2,y2,prevCommand){
  return 'CS'.indexOf(prevCommand)>-1 ? { x1: x1 * 2 - x2, y1: y1 * 2 - y2}
                                      : { x1 : x1, y1 : y1 }
}

function normalizeSegment(segment, params, prevCommand) {
  var nqxy, nxy;
  switch (segment[0]) {
    case "S":
      nxy = shorthandToCubic(params.x1,params.y1, params.x2,params.y2, prevCommand);
      params.x1 = nxy.x1;
      params.y1 = nxy.y1;
      segment = ["C", nxy.x1, nxy.y1].concat(segment.slice(1));
      break
  }
  return segment
}

function normalizePath(pathArray) {
  var params = {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0, x: 0, y: 0, qx: null, qy: null},
      allPathCommands = [], pathCommand = '', prevCommand = '', ii = pathArray.length,
      segment, seglen;
  for (var i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
    pathArray[i] && (pathCommand = pathArray[i][0]);
    allPathCommands[i] = pathCommand;
    i && ( prevCommand = allPathCommands[i - 1]);
    pathArray[i] = normalizeSegment(pathArray[i], params, prevCommand);
    segment = pathArray[i];
    seglen = segment.length;
    params.x1 = +segment[seglen - 2];
    params.y1 = +segment[seglen - 1];
    params.x2 = +(segment[seglen - 4]) || params.x1;
    params.y2 = +(segment[seglen - 3]) || params.y1;
  }
  return pathArray
}

function pathToString(pathArray) {
  return pathArray.map(x=>x[0].concat(x.slice(1).join(' '))).join(' ')
}

function reverse(){
  var reversedCubic = pathToString(reversePath(pathCubic));
  targetCubic.setAttribute('d',reversedCubic)
  targetCubic.closest('.col').innerHTML += '<br><p class="text-left">'+reversedCubic+'</p>'
}
```

```css
.row {width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row}
.col {width: 50%; text-align: center}
.text-left {text-align: left}
```

```html
<button onclick="reverse()">REVERSE</button> Now works with multiple `S` shorthands
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 270 160">
      <path id="example" d="M10 80 C40 10, 65 10, 95 80S 150 150, 180 80S 230 10 270 80" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
    </svg>
    normal path
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 270 160">
      <path id="target" d="M0 0L0 0" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
    </svg>
    reversed CUBIC BEZIER path
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check the latest [SVGPathCommander version on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-commander) or the [demo page](https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/). It can also manage multiple `T` path commands, noo problem.